# Cannot update my database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have an access database that I cannot update. I have successfully updated  a database before, but I could not update another table.

Here is my coding:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Support] SET [progress] = @progress, [personIC] = @personIC, [personSIC] = @personSIC, [personICD] = @personICD WHERE logidticket ='" + Label1.Text + "'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("progress", progress.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("personIC", personIC.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("personSIC", personSIC.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("personICD", personICD.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("itlog.aspx");
    }
```

Those four columns are under Datatype Text.

Any ideas why the data still mistype?

Comment: What do you mean by "why the data still mistype" ? I realize we have a language barrier, but try to clarify your question.  I would guess that the value in your Label1.Text isn't matching logidticket in your WHERE clause, causing it to match no record for update.

Comment: Also, avoid this approach (concatenating input variables into the SQL query). You open your app up to SQL Injection Attacks. There is no reason you shouldn't have also passed Label1.Text as a parameter like the other parameters.

Comment: Hi, thank for comment, yes, as you might be right that the logidticket from my database is "Autonumber" type. Before this page, I session pass the logidticket. Therefore, assuming the logidticket is a "STRING" instead of a "AUTONUMBER"

Comment: Ok, try logging its value or printing it back to the page see what its value is. One good technique is to log the whole statement and then run the SQL statement by hand.

Comment: So, I mention on my "why the data still mistype" is because I cannot update personIC, personSIC, personICD and progress to my database. As you might be right about the logidticket. 

Sorry, I just learnt for couple weeks with this asp.net.

Comment: Hi mrjoltcola, 

Sorry, I am using access database... however, in my webpage (asp.net) it show the same value inside the database. So, am I going to convert the session['logidticket'] to an Integer value?

Comment: Is there any whitespace? If it is an integer, don't quote it.

Comment: dear sir, 
after convert logidticket to int32. I still have the same errors.

Comment: I'm referring to the parameter Label1.Text and where you pass it as  ='" + Label1.Text + "', try removing quotes, make sure Label1.Text has no whitespace

Comment: The error is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." 

After I fill in my form and click the button, I will be showing like this

Comment: Thank You, You discovered my problem! Already work! Thank you very much

Comment: Good, I'll post as answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the value in your Label1.Text isn't matching logidticket in your WHERE clause, causing it to match no record for update.

If logidticket is an integer, remove the quotes. You could have whitespace in your Label text that is throwing it off so the where clause matches no record.

Secondly, avoid concatenating input variables into the SQL query. It is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. Pass Label1.Text as a parameter like the other parameters.

Instead of:

```
WHERE logidticket ='" + Label1.Text + "'
```

do this:

```
WHERE logidticket = @logidticket


cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("logidticket ", Label1.Text);
```